# JS: Slide open multiple divs

Tags: javascript

So I found a script to slide open multiple divs but I can't seem to get it to work. I thought it was something wrong with my main page, but I created a separate page and still can't seem to get it to work.

No messages in debugger, and no errors; but the DIV doesn't appear.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
(function ($) {
    $.fn.showHide = function (options) {

    //default vars for the plugin
        var defaults = {
            speed: 1000,
            easing: '',
            changeText: 0,
            showText: 'Show',
            hideText: 'Hide'

        };
        var options = $.extend(defaults, options);

        $(this).click(function () {
// optionally add the class .toggleDiv to each div you want to automatically close
                      $('.toggleDiv').slideUp(options.speed, options.easing);
             // this var stores which button you've clicked
             var toggleClick = $(this);
             // this reads the rel attribute of the button to determine which div id to toggle
             var toggleDiv = $(this).attr('rel');
             // here we toggle show/hide the correct div at the right speed and using which easing effect
             $(toggleDiv).slideToggle(options.speed, options.easing, function() {
             // this only fires once the animation is completed
             if(options.changeText==1){
             $(toggleDiv).is(":visible") ? toggleClick.text(options.hideText) : toggleClick.text(options.showText);
             }
              });

          return false;

        });

    };
})(jQuery);

</script>
<a class="show_hide" href="#" rel="#slidingDiv">View</a></pre>
<div id="slidingDiv" class="toggleDiv" style="display: none;">Fill this space with really interesting content.</div>
```

Comment: What is not working, and what feedback do you get?

Comment: what is expected, what is happening, any error message?

Comment: Sorry lol, no error message in debugger, and the divs aren't opening

Comment: You have to provide more context for this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is working, for me. You forgot to call function showHide(), actually, and you can do it on this way:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.show_hide').showHide();


});
```

http://jsbin.com/amuhom/1/edit

I have added one div and one button more. I guess this is expected behavior?

Comment: Lol no I expected it to close afterwards. :( but thanks for telling me about my rookie mistake